# Select values between 2 tables order by only data owner

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display product detail order by vendor who posted that product.

Ex :

**Products Table**

```
| ProductIDs | VendorIDs | ProductsName |
----------------------------------------
|    04      |    1      |    Shirt    |
|    05      |    2      |    Pants    |
```

Customer A order `productid 04` from Vendor A and `productid 05` from Vendor B Order table should be :

**Orders Table**
(Customer A ID = 1, Vendor A ID = 1, Vendor B ID = 2)

```
| OrderIDs | VenderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs |
---------------------------------------------------
|    1     | 1, 2      |   04, 05   |      1      |
```

And when Vendor A selected order list I want display `ORDER` and `PRODUCT` detail by only Vendor A or Vendor B should be displayed like this :

Vendor A income order page.

```
| OrderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs | ProductsName |
------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     04     |      1      |     Shirt    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Vendor B income order page.

```
| OrderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs | ProductsName |
------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     05     |      1      |    Pants     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

And Customer A ordered list page.

```
| OrderIDs | ProductIDs | ProductsName |
----------------------------------------
|    1     |   04, 05   | Shirt, Pants |
----------------------------------------
```

And this is code that i've used for selected orders.
`SELECT * FROM Order WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, VendorIDs)`this code will displayed by only first of values in `ProductsName` field like this.

```
| OrderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs | ProductsName |
------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     04     |      1      |    Shirt     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

When i changed `(1, VendorIDs)` to `(2, VendorIDs)` it will displayed in the same result.

Appreciated.

Comment: Don't store your `VenderIDs` and `ProductIDs` as csv. Store them on separate rows in your table. Doing `04, 05` will give you massive headaches down the road.

Comment: I understand that, But i don't know how to store data on separate rows.
When I clicked check out with 2 products from 2 vendors it will insert into database by one row data and I should go back to clicked checkout again to store row data two in database. Could you please tell me how to do?

Comment: Instead of `(OrderIDs | VenderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs) VALUES (1 | 1,2 |  04,05 | 1)`, it would be `(OrderIDs | VenderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs) VALUES (1 | 1 | 04 | 1), (1 | 2 |  05 | 1)`. So you have 1 row for each item. Also, there is no need to have the `VenderIDs` in this table, as you could just use the value in the `Products` table, based off the `ProductID`.

Answer (score 0):

First: you should not have Vendor IDs in your order table.  (if you need to relate Order IDs and Vendor IDs, you will be able to do that through a query.)

Second: each ProductID should be have it's own record in the Orders table:

```
| OrderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs |
---------------------------------------------------
|    1     |   04       |      1      |
|    1     |   05       |      1      |
```

Third: I assume that you will always have a single customer related to each order, and it is unlikely that you will ever have two different customers for one order like this:

```
| OrderIDs | ProductIDs | CustomerIDs |
---------------------------------------------------
|    1     |   04       |      1      |
|    1     |   05       |      5      |
```

Therefore, Customer IDs don't belong in the table that lists the details of the order.  Instead, you should have an **OrderDetails** table:

```
| OrderID | ProductID | 
-----------------------
|    1    |   04      |
|    1    |   05      |
|    2    |   09      |
```

and an **Orders** table:

```
| OrderID | CustomerID |
------------------------
|    1    |      1     |
|    2    |      5     |
|    3    |      5     |
```

If you have any questions after you reconfigure your tables, let me know and I can help you.